# Count number of occurrences of words from a list in a data frame in R

Tags: arrays, r, string, count, stringi

I am working on a little program in R which allows me to count the number of occurrences from a list in a data frame.

I therefore import my data frame and my word list as follows.

```
df <- read.csv("tweets.csv")
wordlist <- read.csv("wordlist.csv")
```

My idea was to use a "for"-loop which runs through all the words in the wordlist, counts their occurrences in the df data frame and then adds the number to the existing wordlist.

```
for (id in wordlist) 
{
wordlist$frequency <- sum(stri_detect_fixed(df$text, wordlist$word))
}
```

Clearly this doesn't work. Instead it adds the frequencies of ALL words in my wordlist to each of the words in the wordlist data frame which looks something like:

```
id  word     freuquency
1   the      1290
2   answer   1290
3   is       1290
4   wrong    1290
```

I know it has to do something with the running variable in my for-loop. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You need to subset `wordlist` using the index `id` somewhere in your for-loop.

Comment: As suggested by @DavidKlotz you need to subset wordlist, for example using indexes, e.g. `for(i in 1:nrow(wordlist)){wordlist$frequency[i]=sum(stri_detect_fixed(df$text, wordlist$word[i]))}`. Of course you need to init frequency to zero before the loop : `wordlist$frequency = 0`

Comment: Seems that this is probably already answered on SO or in a package. You should document you failed searches that is ,,, if you have done any searching.

Comment: Can you give us some example data to work with?

Comment: Example data given below @MattW.

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks! Works just fine.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Fabian posted the question, so I'm more waiting to understand what the tweets.csv is comprised of. Do we know that it's not a separated file?

Comment: @MattW. The tweets.csv is a data frame of 42 variables containing tweets obtained from the Twitter search API. It is a separate file.

Comment: @Fabian, can you bring it into R and use `dput(head(df))` and output the structure so we can use real data in solving this issue?

Comment: @MattW. You can have a look into the real data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fwPJNyo8c0rc6SmGZXrJPRJIgwo3KS60/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Fair point Matt. My bad.

Comment: No worries, you have a good solution. Just wanted to know what his data looked like :)

Answer (score 1):

I would clean the tweets df to turn things to lowercase, remove stopwords, and punctuation etc. (clean the tweets first otherwise you're going to get "Dog" and "dog" as two different words.

```
    x <- c("Heute oft gelesen: Hörmann: «Lieber die Fair-Play-Medaille» als Platz eins t.co/w75t1O3zWQ t.co/fQJ2eUbGLf",
"Lokalsport: Wallbaum versteigert Olympia-Kalender t.co/uH5HnJTwUE",
"Die „politischen Spiele“ sind hiermit eröffnet: t.co/EWSnRmNHlw via @de_sputnik")
wordlist <- c("Olympia", "hiermit", "Die")
```

I would then `sapply` a `tolower` version and parse out by spaces. Then I'd flatten it by using `unlist` so it's a single vector instead of a list, and then unname it so it's a bit easier to read.

```
wordvec <- unname(unlist(sapply(x, function(z) str_split(tolower(z), " "))))

 [1] "heute"                   "oft"                     "gelesen:"                "hörmann:"                "«lieber"                
 [6] "die"                     "fair-play-medaille»"     "als"                     "platz"                   "eins"                   
[11] "t.co/w75t1o3zwq" "t.co/fqj2eubglf" "lokalsport:"             "wallbaum"                "versteigert"            
[16] "olympia-kalender"        "t.co/uh5hnjtwue" "die"                     "\u0084politischen"       "spiele\u0093"           
[21] "sind"                    "hiermit"                 "eröffnet:"               "t.co/ewsnrmnhlw" "via"                    
[26] "@de_sputnik"
```

I think this is still pretty messy. I would look up some text cleaning solutions like removing special characters, or using `grepl` or something to remove the `http` stuff.

To filter the list to only contain your words, try:

```
wordvec[wordvec %in% tolower(wordlist)]
[1] "die"     "die"     "hiermit"
```

And then you can use `table`

```
table(wordvec[wordvec %in% tolower(wordlist)])

die hiermit 
  2       1
```

you can do that last part in reverse if you'd like, but I'd focus on cleaning the texts up to remove the special characters and just do some text cleaning.

Comment: While this is a good solution for if there is spaces, what if there were no spaces? How would you work with the dataset, `data`,  I've provided in my answer?

Comment: Thanks  for the lowercase hint. I will include this in my program.

Comment: My response is the same as Fabian just responded to your with. "dog" would be a part of "dogma", which we don't want. I'm not sure how to handle that issue without a separated datafile. Ultimately I think we need to see an example of this tweets.csv to understand the real problem

Comment: @Fabian can you provide an example of your csv?

Comment: as a note I removed the `http://` because the editor wouldn't let me post without it. Those were included in the example texts I pulled from the doc.

Comment: @MattW. thanks! I'll test my loop version with a text which includes pre-counted words and in case there are discrepancies I'll try it your way.

Comment: the loop will definitely be much slower than a vectorized solution like `sapply`

Comment: @MattW. good to know. I made it run. Maybe this is the way to go for long lists and a lot of data... Thank you for your support!

Comment: @Fabian its a good habit to get into: trying to use the `apply` family over for loops. You'll eventually slow down your code and things will be clunky. Just a tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using sapply. The function checks whether `data` contains 3 consecutive letter combinations and tallies up the count.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
```

**1000 randomly created length 100 letter strings**

```
data <- replicate(100, sample(letters, size = 1000, replace = TRUE))%>%
        data.frame()%>%
        unite("string" , colnames(.) , sep = "", remove = TRUE)%>%
        .$string

head(data)
[1] "uggwaevptdbhhnmvunkcgdssgmulvyxxhnavbxxotwvkvvlycjeftmjufymwzofrhepraqfjlfslynkvbyommaawrvaoscuytfws"
[2] "vftwusfmkzwougqqupeeelcyaefkcxmrqphajcnerfiitttizmpjucohkvsawwiqolkvuofnuarmkriojlnnuvkcreekirfdpsil"
[3] "kbtkrlogalroiulppghcosrpqnryldiuigtsfopsldmcrmnwcwxlhtukvzsujkhqnillzmgwytpneigogvnsxtjgzuuhbjpdvtab"
[4] "cuzqynmbidfwubiuozuhudfqpynnfmkplnyetxxfzvobafmkggiqncykhvmmdrexvxdvtkljppudeiykxsapvpxbbheikydcagey"
[5] "qktsojaevqdegrqunbganigcnvkuxbydepgevcwqqkyekezjddbzqvepodyugwloauxygzgxnwlrjzkyvuihqdfxptwrpsvsdpzf"
[6] "ssfsgxhkankqbrzborfnnvcvqjaykicocxuydzelnuyfljjrhytzgndrktzfglhsuimwjqvvvtvqjsdlnwcbhfdfbsbgdmvfyjef"
```

**Reference to check `data` on**

```
three_consec_letters = expand.grid(letters, letters, letters)%>%
                       unite("consec", colnames(.), sep = "", remove = TRUE)%>%
                       .$consec

head(three_consec_letters)
[1] "aaa" "baa" "caa" "daa" "eaa" "faa"
```

**Check and sum if three_consec_letters  is in lengthy strings**

```
counts = sapply(three_consec_letters, function(x) stri_detect_fixed(data, x)%>%sum())
```

**Results**

```
head(counts)
aaa baa caa daa eaa faa 
  5   6   6   4   0   3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is another option, I guess. Thank you. The problem here is that your count for "is" would also go up if "foolish" occurs. My data frame contains written language from tweets where you usually have a separator between single words. And you don't want to delete that separator.

Comment: If im not mistakened, what I've done above, should work okay with spaces as well. That "foolish" example is a bit troublesome yeah. Ill have to think about this. I guess you need to split each line into a vector and list.

Comment: Vector or list*